# "Invalid workspace: . Error: Could not find configuration file in selected directory: ."

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, web-applications

I'm new to Web app development and every time I open the angular.json file I get this error. This just started happening after I installed bootstrap.

> "Invalid workspace: .
> Error: Could not find configuration file in selected directory: .
> Source: Nx Console (Extension)"

Answer (score 3):

Try these:

1. Locate the tab in the left corner where the menus are explorer, search, source control and etc.
2. click on the Nx Console menu then at the right side of it, click the "Change Workspace". It would open a window where it allows you to choose the workspace.
3. Navigate to the folder where you installed angular.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue after installing bootstrap. To be precise I got the error when I clicked anywhere in angular.json file. I just disabled the Nx Console extension and  the popup didn't occure again.

Not sure this is an efficient solution, but it worked for me and didn't cause any problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue even after disabling Nx Console...so i uninstalled it altogether. Documentation says it is UI for console, which I am not using

Answer (score 0):

I have just disabled the Nx Console as well and it worked for me, never faced the error again or atleast the pop up never showed up

Comment: Since your answer does not provide any new approaches and only confirms an existing answer, consider leaving it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen after a fresh install, if the workspace is not selected in the VSCode extension, or if you change the workspace name / path for any reason (like if you change the scope name or folder).

To solve it, in the VScode (or VSCodium) sidebar, click on the "Nx Console" icon, then you should either see "Change workspace" if it is set, or "Select workspace" if it had never been set.
Then select your workspace (project) root folder, the one containing `nx.json`, it should reload the configuration.